# Could not connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) I cannot access my databases. What I am supposed to do

Tags: php, mysql, sql, passwords

> Could not connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO)

I cannot access my databases using earlier **username (root)** and not any password. What am I supposed to do. I cannot access through mysql console too. I tried to configure config.inc.php file but didn't work.

Please let me know whato to do not to discard WAMP and install new one.

Regards,

Aleksandar

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: do you have a mysql gui client - such as heidi or the mySQL Administrator application?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have forgotten your mysql root user password. I think you should reinstall WAMPP and then set the mysql root user password from command line. To set the mysql root user password you have to first login to mysql from command line using this command: mysql -u root. When it asks for password just enter. After that enter following commands:

```
SET PASSWORD for 'root'@'localhost' = password('enteryourpassword');
SET PASSWORD for 'root'@'127.0.0.1' = password('enteryourpassword');
SET PASSWORD for 'root'@'::1' = password('enteryourpassword');
```